What, if anything, is the generator of point inversion?
An analogy:
linear momentum operator is to translation as angular momentum operator is to rotation
Specifically, the linear-momentum operator is referred to as the generator of translation; the angular-momentum operator is referred to as the generator of rotation.
Questions:
Linear momentum operator is to translation as $\underline{\qquad\qquad\qquad}$   is to point inversion?
In other words, what, if anything, is the generator of point inversion?

Can you have an infinitesimal point inversion? I would have thought not.

I agree with @John Rennie, although if this were an exam question I'd answer "the parity operator"

Note that inversion is different from translation and rotation in that inversion does not preserve chirality, whereas the others do.  Inversion does not correspond to any kind of motion in 3D space or (I think) 4D spacetime that necessarily leaves objects unchanged.

Nothing is the generator of point inversions. Hereafter, I will explain my reasoning.
Consider a Lie group $G$ and its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. An element $A \in G$ is generated by its Lie algebra if
$$A = \exp(X) \text{ for some } X \in \mathfrak{g}.$$
This motivates the definition that generators$^{[1]}$ of a Lie group $G$ are just the basis elements $\{X_i\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$$^{[2]}$.
The parity transformation $\mathcal{P}$ and its applications on itself $\mathcal{P}^n$ do not form a Lie group with a nontrivial Lie algebra$^{[3]}$. Rather, we just get a finite group of two elements $\{\mathcal{P}, e\}$ where $e$ is the group's identity. Even if you consider the Lorentz group $SO(1,3)$, its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ only generates the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$, which does not include parity and time reversal. Hence, there does not exist a Lie algebra element $X$ such that $\mathcal{P} = \exp(X)$, i.e., there is no generator of parity.
In general, there are no generators (in the sense described here) of finite groups of transformations.

[1] In the group theoretic, Lie theoretic, and even physicist sense.
[2] We must note here that not every $A \in G$ can be written in the form $A=\exp(\sum_i c_iX_i)$. In other words, the exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$ is not always surjective.
[3] This is more out of my depth, but discrete groups can apperently be Lie groups. However, any discrete Lie group will have a trivial Lie algebra consisting only of the zero vector $\mathfrak{g} = 0$.

It's the parity operator, defined as
$$ {\hat {\mathcal {P}}}\,\psi {\left(r\right)}=e^{{i\phi }/{2}}\psi {\left(-r\right)} $$
which "flips" the wave-function of particle about origin point.

Please, do not take this as overly fastidious, but can you please confirm the domain of $\phi$? Does the domain span $2\pi$---as in $\phi\in  [0,2\pi)$? Or does the domain span $\pi$---as in $\phi\in  [0,\pi)$?

I see no reasons why QM laws should not allow to do a full phase flip of $\pi$ and as such domain should be $\phi\in  [0,2\pi]$. Both interval ends should be a closed intervals, since $0$ will mean no phase flip at all (just wave-function flip), and $2\pi$ will mean a full phase flip by $\pi$ radians.

In a sense, this answer is not entirely correct. If we want a generator in the Lie theoretic sense, then the parity operator has no generator since there is no Lie algebra associated with the parity transformation.

The Lie algebra of the Lorentz group only generates its identity component (this statement is true for any Lie group). This in particular does not include parity and time inversion operators. @MichaelLevy

The answer strictly depends on the viewpoint and the area of relevance.
From the Lie group point of view, the answer is trivial: there is no generator just because the group is zero-dimensional and thus its tangent space (at the unit element) is made of the zero vector only.
However there is another crucial viewpoint, more related to quantum physics which disregards the notion of exponential.
In the presence of a (continuous) dynamical symmetry group, the generator of the group defines an observable (through Stone's theorem) which is dynamically conserved as a consequence of the existence of the symmetry itself.
From that perspective, the "generator" of the parity symmetry is a selfadjoint operator which is dynamically conserved just in view of the parity symmetry.
Here an answer can be given. The unitary operator (according to Wigner theorem) describing the parity symmetry, by making precise a phase, can be redefined as a unitary and selfadjoint operator $P$.
The (dynamical) symmetry condition
$$PHP^{\dagger}= H,$$
that is
$$PH= HP,$$
implies the conservation equation for the observable
$$e^{itH}Pe^{-itH}=P.$$
From this perspective, the selfadjoint generator of the parity symmetry is the unitary operator defining it made selfadjoint with a choice of its arbitrarily phase (permitted by Wigner's theorem).
ADDENDUM. I prove here my statement above about the choice of the phase. The Wigner theorem proves that there is a unitary or antiunitary operator (depending on the considered symmetry) representing the said symmetry. This operator is defined up to a phase. I suppose that the said operator $U$  is unitary (it can be proved for specific physical systems when also assuming that the symmetry is dynamical: that it leaves invariant time evolution). From physical reasons $UU$ does not change anything, and thus it is a pure phase:
$$UU= e^{ia}I.$$
Therefore, $$P:= e^{-ia/2}U$$
satisfies
$$PP=I.$$
On the other hand, $P$ is unitary (because $U$ is), so that
$$PP^{\dagger}=I.$$
Uniqueness of the inverse operator implies:
$$P=P^{\dagger}.$$
